# what happened to www.alro7.net

Tags: tafseer, islamic-resources

Does anyone know what happened to the domain [www.alro7.net](http://www.alro7.net) which was a comprehensive database for tafsirs which has an option for searching a verse and it will give the tafsirs for the verse from a number of mufassirs like ibh kathir, qurtubi, tabari, jalalyn, etc.
The domain is not active now, as it shows the domain has expired.